# Search Keyword from multiple Excel colomn/row in multiples pdf files

Tags: python

I am new in the python world and I try to build a solution I struggle to develop. The goal is to check that some mandatory information (it will be keywords) are present in a pdf. I have an Excel file where each row correspond to a transaction, and I need to check that all the transaction (and the mandatory information related to them) are in the a corresponding PDF sent during the day.

So, on one side, I have several Excel row in a sheet with the mandatory information (corresponding to info on each transaction), and on the other side, I have a folder with several PDF.

I try to extract data of each pdf to allow the workflow to check if the information for each row in my Excel file are in a single pdf. I check some question raised here and tried to apply some solution to my problem, but I haven't managed to obtain a full working solution.

I have been able to build the partial code that will extract the pdf data and look for the keywords:

```
Import os
from glob import glob
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def search_page(pattern, page):
    yield from pattern.findall(page.extractText())

def search_document(pattern, path):
    document = PdfFileReader(path)
    for page in document.pages:
        yield from search_page(pattern, page)

searchWords = ['my list of keywords in each row of my Excel file']
pattern = re.compiler(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(searchWords))

for path in glob('path of my folder with all the pdf files'):
    matches = search_document(pattern, path)
```

#inspired by a solution on stackoverflow used to count the occurences of keywords

Also, I think that using panda to build the list of keyword should work, but I can't use it in me previous code, the search tool want a string, not a list.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('path of my Excel file', sheet_name=0, usecols='G,L,R,S,Z')
print(df) #I wanted to check that the code was selecting the right colomn only, as some other colomn have unnecessary information
```

I don't know how to do a searchwords list for each row of my Excel file and put it in the first part of the code. Also, I don't know how to ask to search for ALL the keywords of the list (row in excel), as it is mandatory to have all the information of a transaction in the same pdf. And when it finds all the info, return "ok row 1" or something like that and do the check for the second row, etc. (and put error if it doesn't find all the information).

P.S.: Originally, I wanted only to extract the data with a python code and add it in an Alteryx Workflow, but the python tool of alteryx doesn't accept some Package in my company.

I would be very thankfull for any help!

Comment: Can you share some sample i/p(both excel and pdf) and expected o/p.

Moreover does the ordering of the words matter of the excel matter i.e bigram/ngram(sequence of words) or just keywords.

Based on what is shared:
- Read multiple excel and generate `search_list`
- Read files and tokenize(and/or remove punctuation) using ntlk or string package.
- Generate a list of input_keywords.
- Iterate and check presence of all search_list in input_keywords using all[https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all] func.